# express/node: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having some issues with my expressJS application, posting to one route will always result in `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` - I don't understand why and where I'm sending a request/response twice.

I tried playing around with `async` and `await` in my functions to get rid of this error but ultimately it's always coming back. I'm also writing an ID to a database, I thought this would be the issue. But I don't think so, because I'm basically just returning a code and not even checking the `dynamodb.put` request in my current function.

```
async function putNewUrl(inputUrl) {
  const newId = await getId();
  const short = ShortURL.encode(newId);

  const params = {
    TableName: URL_TABLE,
    Item: {
      long: inputUrl,
      short,
    },
  };

  try {
    const data = await dynamoDb.put(params).promise();
    return short;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return short;
}
```

```
app.post('/submit', async (req, res) => {
  const inputUrl = req.body.url;

  try {
    const shortUrl = await putNewUrl(inputUrl);
    console.log(shortUrl)
    return res.json({ success: true, message: shortUrl });
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
    return
  }
});
```

here are my imports:

```
import { config, DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';

import { json } from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import { URL } from 'url';

const app = express();
app.use(helmet());
```

this is how I start my server

```
app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('app running'); });
```

**solved it**:

there was another route like this:

```
app.post('/submit', (req, res, next) => {
  const inputUrl = req.body.url;
  findExistingUrl(inputUrl, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.json({ success: false, message: 'server error' });
    }
    if (typeof data.Items[0] === 'undefined' && data.Items[0] !== null) {
      next();
    } else {
      return res.json({ success: true});
    }
  });
});
```

where I was calling `next()` right at the end again.

Comment: are you using any express middlewares? Nothing in your code looks like it would be causing this issue.

Comment: What @Turtlefight said. Post your code that starts up your server, as it likely is adding in middleware that is modifying headers.

Comment: And to add to those two, if they are adding/ modifying headers, make sure your route comes after them in your code.

Comment: @Turtlefight I added the code how I'm starting the server and the imports

Comment: @CalIrvine I'm using helmet, my route comes after enabling helmet. Without helmet I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it:

there was another route like this:

```
app.post('/submit', (req, res, next) => {
  const inputUrl = req.body.url;
  findExistingUrl(inputUrl, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.json({ success: false, message: 'server error' });
    }
    if (typeof data.Items[0] === 'undefined' && data.Items[0] !== null) {
      next();
    } else {
      return res.json({ success: true});
    }
  });
});
```

where I was calling next() right at the end again.